# Rspec has_one relation error when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have User (which is I used Devise) and Profile model where User has_one Profile as their relationship. I got an error when run the rspec test. Below is my spec to handle when user is updating his/her profile.

`spec/controller/profiles_controller_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe ProfilesController, type: :controller do
  let(:profile) { FactoryGirl.create(:profile) }
  let (:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:profile) }
  let (:invalid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:profile).merge({fname: nil}) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:valid_session) { sign_in(user) }

  describe "PUT #update" do
    before { valid_session }

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves valid profile" do
        expect do
          put :update, { id: profile.id, profile: { fname: "Cena" } }
        end.to change{ profile.reload.fname }.to("Cena")
      end
    end
```

`spec/factories/profiles.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    user 
    fname "John"
    lname "Doe"
    avatar "my_avatar"
  end
end
```

`app/controller/profiles_controller.rb`

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id, :login, :email,
      profile_attributes: [
        :id, :user_id, :fname, :lname, :avatar, :avatar_cache
      ])
  end

end
```

And here is the error when run `rspec spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb`

```
Failures:

  1) AccountsController PUT #update with valid attributes saves valid profile
     Failure/Error: put :update, {id: profile.id, user_id: user.id, profile: { fname: "Cena" }}
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:profile) { FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user_id: user.id ) }

  describe "PUT #update" do
    before { valid_session }

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves valid profile" do
        expect do
          put :update, id: user.id, user: { profile_attributes: { user_id: user.id, fname: "Cena" } }
        end.to change{ profile.reload.fname }.to("Cena")
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: still not working.. then i got another error when use your solution:

`NoMethodError: undefined method "permit"`

Comment: can you try my updated answer and see if that works?

Comment: i got this error `"id" is not available from within an example (e.g. an "it" block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. "before", "let", etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a "describe" or "context" block).`

Comment: got this error `expected result to have changed to "Cena", but did not change`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92454/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-amirolahmad).

Answer (score 0):

The profiles_controller.rb code you posted is missing the update action (and also the class name is AccountController), but I guess you are doing something like `user.update(user_params)`.

If that's the case, as the error says, the params passed from the controller spec does not have `:user` key, and that is causing the error.

Assuming from the #user_params method and the error, the params passed to the post in controller spec needs to look like the following:

```
{ 
  user: {
    id: xxx, ...,
    profile_attributes: {
      id: xxx, 
      fname: xxx, ...
    }
   }
}
```